# @font-face changes Leaflet.js popup behaviour

Tags: javascript, leaflet, font-face

I have a popup in Leaflet.js which on its own works fine (with a normal font). But when I add a custom `font-family` to it through `@font-face` the popup loads as two lines of text instead of one.

Refreshing the page causes the popup to behave normally again, but when loading the page for the first time (as in opening a new tab) it defaults to this odd behaviour.

I have tried playing around with `line-height`, `font-size`, `L.popup({ min/maxWidth })`, order of stylesheets etc. none of which seemed to work.

The `<p>` tag inside `.setContent()` is necessary for the popup to be styled properly. I have tried several workarounds which neither seemed to work (which might solve the problem).

[image]

**Vs**

[image]

**[Working example](https://radllaufer.github.io/Leaflet)**

---

#### JS

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([41.9, 12.46], 6);

const address = L.popup({
    className: "popup-address",
}).setLatLng([42, 12.46])
    .setContent('<p>All roads lead to Rome</p>')
    .openOn(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

#### CSS

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: 500;
   src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTUPjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WxZOg3z_PZw.woff2) format('woff2');
   unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
        
#map {
   margin: 5rem auto;
   height: 400px;
   width: 600px;
}

.popup-address p {
   font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

---

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that Leaflet calculates the width of the popup before the font is loaded and applied to the popup content. This is only happens on first call, because after the font is in the cache.

A workaround is to add a hidden text in the html, so that the font is download from beginning. Else the font would be loaded the first time when the popup is created / opened.

HTML:

```
<span class="font-loaded">Preload the font ... </span>
```

CSS: (It's important to **NOT** use `display: none` else the element would not be rendered and the font will not downloaded)

```
.font-loaded{
            font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
            position: absolute;
            left: -100px;
            top: -100px;
        }
```

JS: (open the popup if the font is downloaded and the window is rendered)

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const address = L.popup({
          className: "popup-address",
      }).setLatLng([42, 12.46])
          .setContent('<p>All roads lead to Rome</p>')
          .openOn(map);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Falke Designs answer I changed the javascript slightly so I'm able to use methods on `address` later on:

```js
let address = L.popup({
    className: "popup-address",
}).setLatLng([42, 12.46])
    .setContent('<p>All roads lead to Rome</p>');

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   address.openOn(map);
}
```